# Get user information in localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I want the information to be stored individually in localStorage.
If the entered information is already available, do not receive the information again and give an alert. Is it possible to guide me, what should I do?

```js
function handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]")
  users.push(values)
        
  localStorage.setItem('users', JSON.stringify(users))
        
  const loggeduser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users") || "[]");
  if (
    values.email === loggeduser.email &&
    values.password === loggeduser.password
  ) {
    alert("Emaill & Password is available!!!")
  } else {
    navigate("/");
  }
};
```

Several users are stored in one presentation and not separately.
The alert also works incorrectly.

Comment: Looks like the code is already accessing user data from localStorage. Don't store all user's data under the same `"users"` storage key? ‍♂️ Or I guess that's ok and you just need to search the `users` array for a match? It's unclear what you really need help with here. What exactly is the problem you are asking for help with?

Comment: @DrewReese
After sending user information to localstorage, this information is stored in a presentation.
user  [{"email":"as@gmial.om","password":"1234"},{"email":"ex@gmail.com","password":"321"}]
I want this information to be stored separately in each value

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean? What "information to be store separately in each value" means?

Comment: @DrewReese
I'm sorry that I couldn't get my point across yet.
I want to store each value of a user's information separately.
like this:
user [{"email":"as@gmial.om","password":"1234"}]
user [{"email":"ex@gmail.com","password":"321"}]
...

Comment: Aye, I see, then my initial comment applies I think, not storing an array of all user's info, but storing them descretely.

Comment: @DrewReese
So do you think this code has no problem?
And is it working without problems?

Comment: I can't speak to its correctness since I don't really understand what it's trying to accomplish. It looks syntactically correct and should compile if that's what you want to know.